# It is possible to force update a running winform application without restart it using ClickOne publishing?

Tags: winforms, clickonce, publish, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I try all the possible configuration in ClickOnce but the application only updates on restart.

I want the application to update after the application startup but in VS 2022 the update after startup is blocked as we can see in the following image:

[image]

I am using .net core 6 and my IDE is VS2022.

Comment: If you check for updates after application startup, then restart of application is necessary for updates to take effect. If you check for updates before application startup, the application updates first, then it runs.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I want the application to update after the application startup but in VS 2022 the update after startup is blocked as you can see in the image that I added to the question.

Comment: According to the [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/choosing-a-clickonce-update-strategy?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#check-for-updates-before-application-startup): *For .NET 3.1 and newer applications, checking updates before the application starts is the only update option supported.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/choosing-a-clickonce-update-strategy?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#check-for-updates-before-application-startup), *checking for update before the application starts*, is the default and only option available for .NET 3.1 and newer versions:

> *For .NET 3.1 and newer applications, checking updates before the application starts is the only update option supported.*

**ClickOnce update strategies**

Here is a summary of main ClickOnce update strategies:

- ***Automatic update - Check for updates after application startup***

  In this strategy, ClickOnce will check updates in the background when the application starts. Then, the next time when the user starts the application, based on the result of previous check-for-update, if an update was available, it shows a prompt to the user asking to download and install the updates.

  Main use-case for this scenario is low-bandwidth networks or large applications when updates takes longer to download and install.
- ***Automatic update - Check for updates before application startup***

  In this strategy, every time the user starts the application, the application first checks for an update and if an update is available, it downloads and applies the updates and then start the application.

  It's the default strategy and as I mentioned above, it's the only available option for .NET 3.1 and above.

  Main use-case for this scenario is high-bandwidth networks and also cases which you want to make the update mandatory.
- **Manual update - Provide a user interface for updates**

  In this strategy, developer writes code using the [ApplicationDeployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) class to check for updates; For example checking for update based on when users clicks on a menu item or button; or based on a custom user-defined schedule.

  The main usage scenario for this strategy is when you want to have different strategies for different users, or custom scheduled updates for different users, or to have a manual check for update button/menu.

To learn more, take a look at the following doc articles:

- [Choose a ClickOnce update strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/choosing-a-clickonce-update-strategy?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#check-for-updates-before-application-startup)
- [How ClickOnce performs application updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-clickonce-performs-application-updates?view=vs-2022&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
- [How to: Check for application updates programmatically using the ClickOnce deployment API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-check-for-application-updates-programmatically-using-the-clickonce-deployment-api?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)